# Tomcat Server Not Working with Intellij Idea

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to deploy a project using Tomcat 7 server and JDK 1.6 with the Intellij Idea 2017.2 ,. But when start the server it shows an error message " SSL HTTP connector node not found:set up one in the server.xml".It shows even set up the HTTP connector in server.xml.How to resolve this issue?

**Error message show in the IDE**

[image]

Comment: screen shot with the error message has been attached.

Comment: Make sure that your `CATALINA_BASE\conf\server.xml` has the [corresponding code](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165460#comment=27-1838583) configured. You can check the directory for the CATALINA_BASE variable in the console output when you start the server in IDE.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was to remove the HTTPS port in the Run/Debug Configurations dialog.